# A function of equal length

Tags: math, geometry, game-physics, vertex-shader

I am planning to build in a bending technique into the GPU. Like bending a stick. It doesn't have to do real physics, but I do want the bending function (to displace the vertices) to have an equal length.

My function will be built out of 2 components:

- The y-position of the stick
- The force against the stick (general, not on a specific place, like wind)

I am bending into the x-direction. I could create some `x = y * force` formula, but the problem is that this will deform the object in its length.

> How can I deform the object, but keep its actual length? How can I constraint my function?

Or in another way:

> How can I adjust the power of a polynomial function, while keeping the length over a y-interval? eg. [0,1]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a circular deformation and you should keep the central length unchanged, here you may see the associated formulas:

[image]

[image]